# Integral of $e^{-\|x\|_\infty}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, what is the integral of $ e^{-\|x\|_\infty}$? Thus, I can find a probability density function which has the form $p(x) = \frac 1z e^{-\|x\|_\infty}$.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say the integral over $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the same as $2^d$ times the integral over $[0,\infty)^d$, which is $d!$ times

$$ \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{x_d}\cdots \int_0^{x_2} e^{-x_d}\,\mathrm{d}x_1\cdots\mathrm{d}x_d .$$

That is, $d!$ times the integral of $\exp(-\|x\|_{\infty})$ over the region defined by

$$ \{(x_1,\cdots,x_d)\mid 0\le x_1\le\cdots\le x_d\}. $$

The constant $e^{-x_d}$ can be pulled out of all but one integral, then the inner integrals can be evaluated one by one with the power rule to obtain

$$ I=2^d d! \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{d-1}}{(d-1)!}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x=2^d\frac{d!}{(d-1)!}\Gamma(d)=2^dd!. $$